# whats the difference between using StaticRouter and MemoryRouter for testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-dom

Am curious to know what's the difference between using StaticRouter to support the links in react-router-dom and using MemoryRouter. They both act seem to be able to support my link.